# Can I equate Epics to a business unit?

Tags: tfs

I manage the application development group for a local county health plan and we are using TFS to manage a mixture of activities like production support, development activities, and data analysis research.  We use the Scrum template.

We have been using On Premise TSF 2017 for a few months now and recently turned on Epics.    Since this is not a pure development group, we have had to adjust the TFS terms to fit our needs and I'd like to understand if how we are using Epics/Feature/PBIs is within reason or way off base.

We are using Epics and Features simply as a way to categorize PBI's.  We view PBI's as small projects that have tasks.  We found it useful to map Epics and Features to our business terminology below:

Epics = Business Unit 
         eg. Finance, claims, Customer Service
Features = Initiative, Application, Support
         eg. Data warehouse, Claim system, automated production issues

As you can see, our use of Epics and some of our Features (automated production issues) do not have a completion date since they represent ongoing concerns, is this a problem?   We chose this structure because it gives our users a more natural way to navigate the maze of PBIs via the TFS web interface, greatly easing finding existing PBI's and adding new PBIs to the correct Feature.

I know there are other fields we could have used to achieve this like 'Area', 'Value area', 'Business Value', and even the Iteration Paths but they don't have the built in benefit of drilling down via the default web interface on the Backlogs tab.

How successful can we be using TFS like this or are we should we stop now and restructure?

Comment: For the common practice that in line with Scrum Framework, you can refer to this article for details : [Requirements (Epic, Feature, User Story), Task Size and Estimation in Agile and Scrum](http://mohamedradwan.com/2017/12/05/requirements-epic-feature-user-story-task-size-and-estimation-in-agile-and-scrum/). But TFS is just a tool   which help us manage the project. So, If the practice applies to your project management, then it's OK.

Comment: Andy, thanks for the reassurance that it is okay for us to use TFS in this fashion.  Thanks for the link.  I've read these documents and other similar docs but they all, understandably, focus on pure software development.

Answer (score 0):

TFS is a ALM tool that provides source code management, reporting, requirements management, project management, automated builds, lab management, testing and release management capabilities. It covers the entire application lifecycle.

As I menioned in above comment, generally we will follow the standard process to use the TFS. Yes, as you said, they all understandably and focus on pure software development. ( *For the common practice that in line with Scrum , you can refer to this article for details : [Requirements (Epic, Feature, User Story), Task Size and Estimation in Agile and Scrum](http://mohamedradwan.com/2017/12/05/requirements-epic-feature-user-story-task-size-and-estimation-in-agile-and-scrum/).* )

But TFS is just a tool which help us manage the project. In your scenario, it's more based on the experience or special requirements. So, If the practice applies to your project management, then it's OK.